# Angularjs: fixing scope so directive can be duplicated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fix my scopes so that if I duplicate my directive it will still work. Right now I have the following program flow:
1. A controller creates a variable called prefix and populates it with a value (JOE).
2. The directive prompts the user for a suffix (say DOE) and then concatenates the prefix and the suffix.
3. The controller then displays the concatenated value (JOEDOE).

Here is my html:

```
<div ng-controller="cntrl">
    <div>Prefix: {{prefix}}</div>
    <div >Concatenated value: {{concatenatedName}}</div>
    <!--Below is the directive-->
    <div entering="{{prefix}}" joinit></div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
var myMod = angular.module('MyModule', []);

myMod.controller('cntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.prefix="JOE";
    $scope.concatenatedName="";
    $scope.concatenate = function (param) {
        $scope.concatenatedName=param;
    };
});

myMod.directive('joinit', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "<div>Suffix: <input type='text' id='suffix'/>" +
    "<button ng-click='click()'>Concatenate</button> </div>",
    controller: function($scope, $element){
      $scope.click = function(){
        var concatVar = $element[0].attributes[0].value + 
                    document.getElementById('suffix').value;
        $scope.concatenate(concatVar);
      }
    }
};
});
```

The code works fine and provides a simple example of a basic function a directive should be able to carry out: it prompts the user for input, the input is combined with controller data and returned to the controller for display or for persisting (thru a service). The trouble is that this directive can't be duplicated.  If I isolate the scope (as in scope:{},) the directive no longer has access to $scope.

Here is a link to the working example (it doesn't work in jsfiddle so I've put in on my own server):

http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~lfernandez/angular/ang.html

Comment: If you isolate the scope, you don't NEED directive access to your parent scope. That's the whole point of encapsulation. You can use an isolated scope with a bi-directional binding and $watch instead.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, it might be rough... but an isolated scope is your answer:

```
myMod.directive('joinit', function () {
return {
restrict: 'A',
scope:{suffix:'='},
template: "<div>Suffix: <input type='text' ng-model='suffix_value'/>" +
"<button ng-click='click()'>Concatenate</button> </div>",
controller: function($scope, $element){
  $scope.click = function(){
    $scope.suffix = angular.copy($scope.suffix_value);
  }
}
};
});
```

Now you see we're just setting suffix when you click, thanks to ng-model we dont' need any of that other element stuff.

Now pass something into suffix so it can do its magic

```
<div suffix="someSuffix" joinit></div>
```

Now in your parent controller you can do whatever you want with `someSuffix`

```
$scope.concatenate = function (whatever) {
  return $scope.prefix + whatever;
}
```

and now

```
{{concatenate(someSuffix)}}
```

will return what you expect.

side note: if you're having trouble with jsFiddle try [plnkr.co,](http://plnkr.co/) there's a pre-built angular app template in the editor. If you're still having trouble post your code in plnkr and maybe I can help.

Comment: You might point out the difference between an isolate scope (scope: {}) and creating a new child scope (scope: true) in the directive's definition. Both will create a new scope, but the isolate scope will not inherit the scope of the parent. For directives that you re-use, the isolate scope generally is the right choice. But sometimes you do want your directive to inherit properties from the parent scope.

Comment: J.R.'s code was very helpful.  I put it into http://jsbin.com/qegan/1/ and it runs fine there. I still don't get why something like this (combined say with a jquery datepicker) wouldn't be a more common example to present in directive tutorials.  I mean isn't the most common use case for a directive to bind data between a controller and the directive, and then have the directive update some value that the controller would then persist through a service?  Yet O'Reilly and Egghead.io don't show examples like that.  Next thing is to combine this code with: http://tinyurl.com/ldzgnb6

Comment: Here's a modified version of the above that binds a controller date with a directive and allows the user to update the date thru the directive: http://jsbin.com/gab/2/ Another thing I learned from this: with isolated scope the directive controller and the directive template are in an encapulated microcosm. So an ng-bind in the directive template is only binding with the scope in the directive's controller! Then, to bind with a variable named date in the directive's parent scope (e.g a traditional controller) one says:  scope:{date:'='} and date="date" in the directive's element.